# Is it possible to upload that email back to the server?

Tags: email

I check my email in multiple places, so I need my email to remain on my server until I delete it. I installed thunderbird and didn't notice the "leave mail on server for at most 14 days" check box. Tbird downloaded and erased all of my email except for the last 14 days.

Is there a way to upload that email back to the server?

Comment: You can always email them to yourself - not ideal, but if it is a question of having it online or not, this could be a quick or temporary fix.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can if the connection is made with POP (Post Office Protocol), which it appears to be how you are connecting.

If your email provider supports IMAP (Internet Message Access Protocol) it would be an easy process to restore those messages on the server.

To restore the messages using IMAP connection:

1. Back up your email to be safe.
2. Create the IMAP account in TBird.
3. Do a little testing by sending/receiving a few emails to make sure it works.
4. Select the messages you want to upload back to the server.
5. Right-click the messages and choose to COPY the messages into the "Inbox" of the new IMAP account.
6. You are done. The messages you put into the "Inbox" will be restored to your email server.

It will take a few minutes, to a few hours or more to complete the upload depending on your volume of email and connection speed. Most likely, it will be much faster than the old connection (POP).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your mail server supports IMAP and if it does you can switch your account from POP3 to IMAP and then upload all your mesages back to the folder on your server. And you can also switch all other accounts on other computers to IMAP and then you will be checking your email right on the server. And its not going to go anywhere from the server. Its going to have a copy on your local computer but it will also leave a copy on your server. Thats how gmail works and thats how yahoo works.